# Are there functions in Google Docs scripting that provide access to copy and paste

Tags: google-apps-script, clipboard, copy-paste

I've searched the API docs and can't see any references to `copy` and `paste`.

Specifically what I want to do is the following:

- In `Document1`, select all the text, `Copy` to the clipboard.
- In `Document2`, select all the text, `Paste` from the clipboard.

So the net effect is to replace the contents of `Document2` with the contents of `Document1`.

I realise you could do this with the script equivalent of the menu operation `File/Make a copy`, but I don't want the key for `Document2` to change.

** EDIT **

I have got this far based on other SO posts I have seen, and it largely works, but no images are getting copied across to the destination document, just placeholders of the correct dimension.  Does anyone know why this might be?

```
var SourceDocKey = "abcd..." ;
var DestDocKey   = "efgh..." ;  

var SourceDoc = DocumentApp.openById (SourceDocKey) ;
var DestDoc   = DocumentApp.openById (DestDocKey) ;

var SourceBody = SourceDoc.getBody () ;
var DestBody   = DestDoc.getBody () ;

DestBody.clear () ;
var TotalElements = SourceBody.getNumChildren () ;

for (var j = 0 ; j < TotalElements ; ++j) 
  {
  var Element = SourceBody.getChild(j).copy();
  var type = Element.getType();
  if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH)
    {
    var ParagraphChildren = Element.asParagraph().getNumChildren() ;  
    if (ParagraphChildren != 0 && 
        Element.asParagraph().getChild (0).getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.INLINE_IMAGE) 
      {
      var blob = Element.asParagraph().getChild(0).asInlineImage().getBlob();
      DestBody.appendImage(blob) ;
      }
    else 
      DestBody.appendParagraph(Element.asParagraph());
    }
  else if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.TEXT ) 
    DestBody.setText(Element);

  else if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE )
    DestBody.appendTable(Element);
  else if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM )
    DestBody.appendListItem(Element);
  else if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.INLINE_IMAGE )
    DestBody.appendImage(Element);
  else if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.HORIZONTAL_RULE) 
    DestBody.appendHorizontalRule();
  else if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.PAGE_BREAK) 
    DestBody.appendPageBreak();

  // add other element types as you want

  else
    throw new Error("Unhandled element type: " +type) ;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

are you looking for something like that?

```
function copypaste(){
 var cible = "ID_OF_THE_DESTINATION_DOCUMENT";
 var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
 var dest = DocumentApp.openById(cible).getBody();
 dest.clear();
 var para = body.getParagraphs();
 for(var i =0;i<para.length;i++){
   dest.appendParagraph(para[i].copy());
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Harold.  Almost there - the document text and images made it through, but minus the tables.  I'm assuming that maybe I need to iterate through the elements rather than the paragraphs?  This is one reason why I thought that using copy and paste programmatically would be better as an initial Select All would grab everything. (and especially as that's the way I do it currently - manually).

Comment: Please see additions to question.